# Clean Architecture in NodeJS, how do useCases interact with each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, clean-architecture

I am trying to implement the Clean Architecture by Bob Martin in my project and I have a question.

How do use-cases interact with each other?

For example:

I have a `Department` entity and `Employee` entity.

Department entity has a `peopleCount` field

Whenever a new `Emplyoee` is created it is also assigned to a `Department`, which means that `peopleCount` must increase by 1.

So how should that interaction between say `addEmployee.js` and `editDepartment.js` use-cases be?

Do I `const editDepartment = require("../departments");` within my `addEmployee.js` and use it within `addEmployee.js`?

Do I inject it as a dependency and then use it?

Do I create a separate useCase `increasePeopleCountInDepartmentById.js` and require/inject that one? So that its something with a specific purpose and not the "general" editing.

Answer (score 0):

> How do use-cases interact with each other?

A use-case is a scenario in which a system receives an external request (such as user input) and, following a list of actions, responds to it ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case)). Therefore, use-cases by definition cannot interact with each other. Moreover, they have not interest to interact with each other.

A use-case, be it addEmployee or editDepartment (depending on your system design), should orchestrate participating domain entities (employee and department). Again, mixing use-cases is irrelevant.

Here's how you can implement addEmployee:

```
// TODO: start database transaction
const newEmployee = employeeFactory.create(id, name, age, targetDepartmentId);
const department = departmentRepository.get(targetDepartmentId);
department.peopleCount = department.peopleCount + 1;
departmentRepository.save(department);
employeeRepository.add(newEmployee);
// TODO: commit transaction
```

> Do I inject it as a dependency and then use it?

As can be inferred from my example, three objects are to be injected into use-case: employeeFactory, departmentRepository, employeeRepository.